# The tailgate does not close properly

Tags: skoda, octavia, latch, tailgate

The car is 2012 Skoda Octavia(1Z) and the tailgate does not close smoothly. It went to the service for another problem in the trunk then this happened. Normally it closes from very low height properly and silently. Now tailgate does not close at the same height so I need to drop it from higher height. It makes too much sound and different noises that comes from glass and other parts.

I assume adjusting bottom latch position that may solve the problem but what could be the reason of the problem?

After Investigation Edit:
I checked the 'gate thoroughly today and realised that it is tilted. I guess it explains the noises and not closing. So the problem is tailgate stands closer to the left. There is small gap between left panel and gate and huge gap(60mm or even 1cm) between gate and right body panel. In this situation how can I adjust it?

[image: not my car, representetive]

Comment: what work was done? that may have a huge impact on what you need to look at...

Comment: There was a water in spare tyre well and work done for that. Which bearing do you mention?

Comment: Bearing as in impact or effect, not bearing as in roller or needle.... Is there any sign of impact (impact as in damage ie paint chipped, or bent... etc) on an edge of the tailgate ie is it possible they hit it with something?

Comment: I did not look at specifically for any damages. But not noticed anything faulty.

Comment: I assume that the mechanic tried to adjust the lock latch position, so that the hatch presses firmly against the rubber seals to keep water out of your car trunk. Just posting this as a comment as it is just a thought and no solution to your problem